# Redux State does not update what has been removed from database on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Need some assistance
I have a query from firestore that returns an array of events that the user is a member of.

```
Array [
  Object {
    "eventName":"Why wont this update",
    "eventId": "2s4CWlbAApgDbhmvgJm6",
    "eventImage": "www.image.com",
  
  },
] 

the objects retrieved from the firestore query shown above are pushed into an array called eventsJoined then a dispatch is called shown below.
```

An action is called and the state is updated.

```
  dispatch({
                    type: GET_USER_EVENTS,
                    eventsJoined: eventsJoined,
                })
```

here is the reducer

```
export const events= (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
case GET_USER_EVENTS:       
            return {
                ...state,
                eventsJoined: action.eventsJoined,
                loaded: action.loaded
            }
  }
}
```

The state gets updated and the new event is added but when the event is removed from the database the state still has the event in it and doesnt update even after refetching the data. The firestore query retrieves all the events the users has joined but the state doesnt update.

Is there a way to update the state and remove events that the user isn't going to any more and also get the new events the user is now going to?

Comment: Where is `eventsJoined` coming from?

Comment: the events joined in an array of objects. The data comes from a firestore query  that retrieves all the events (and their info) a user is going to.

Comment: Have you tried to log `eventsJoined `? Does it have correct values?

Comment: Yes it does but the redux state showing the `eventsJoined`  doesnt update with the new values when one of them is removed from the database.

Comment: Can't find any issue in your current code. There must be something that you have omitted.